# Trouble with complex MySQL command. Can I make a compound statement like this?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, prepared-statement

Can I search for an element in the database where my PreparedStatement has for one of it's arguments the value found from a variable which I'd normally make as a separate statement?

So I want to do

```
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE Name = ? AND WHERE  user_ID = ?);  
preparedStatement.setString(1, name);  
preparedStatement.setString(2, userID);    
rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Except as it stands I'd need a separate statement to find the userID variable in another table.
Something like:

```
preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE name = ?);  
preparedStatement.setString(1, theirName);
```

So is there a way to compound these into two statements?  ie:  Something like...

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1 WHERE Name = (user_ID FROM users WHERE username = theirName);
```

edit: This may be more clear. Imagine I have a table of Cars, where each car has a name and an Owner_ID.
And I have a table of users where each user has a name, password, and ID.
Every car's owner ID is one of the user's ID's.

And so what I really want to get (in a single statement) is the count of all the cars with name X where their owner ID = id from of user Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by joining tables together:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t1.name = "John" AND t2.user_ID = 2342433
```

Comment: This might be what I'm looking for, but is it any more or less efficient than getting the second variable (which I'd need in a combined statement) by doing a separate query like  
like "SELECT id FROM users where USERNAME = theirName"

Comment: It is more efficient because the compiler has an opportunity to optimize your call. In case of separate queries it saves two outputs independently which is certainly slower.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  And it turns out either join or Inner join is what I need.

Comment: Welcome. FYI, INNER JOIN is equivalent to JOIN.

Comment: Yes, it is to differentiate easily between INNER JOIN and OUTER JOIN. Functionality is identical.